# How to send String[] intent extra value from command line?

Tags: android, string, android-intent, command-line, adb

My automated test sends intents via `adb shell am`, but I'm having trouble specifying an extra that is a *String Array*.

According to the [Intent class docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), it is possible to put an *String[]* extra to an intent.

However the [Intent specification docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#IntentSpec) for the `am` command does not list a string array type. The only string types I can see in the docs is normal string and perhaps null "string":

```
--esn <EXTRA_KEY>
    Add a null extra. This option is not supported for URI intents. 
-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>
    Add string data as a key-value pair.
```

Is it avoidable to write a java application for the mere purpose of sending string arrays?

Is there a way to send a *String[]* extra from the command line?

**edit** in case this is not possible this way, what is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 27):

Old question, but unanswered.
`adb shell am` shows all the options, among them there's:

```
[--esa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_STRING_VALUE...]]
    (to embed a comma into a string escape it using "\,")
```

Comment: probably this was introduced recently, I think there were no such option previously, as seen in [sean loyola's anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26517290/611007). good to know its now available, thanks! Previously, I ended up using a custom program I've created for jobs like this.

Comment: Yes, it is new API. I didn't find when it was introduced.

Comment: BIG thank you for this comment. This solved a one hour debugging session. :)

Answer (score 21):

For anyone else looking for this the command line flags for extras are listed below

```
-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>
--esn <EXTRA_KEY>
--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE>
--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>
--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>
--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>
--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE>
--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]
--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]
--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]
```

Comment: And your solution for a String[] is?

Comment: how about double? ```--ed``` didn't work!

Answer (score 5):

The action and data uri to launch

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://www.google.com"
```

The action like send sms, mime type and an extra string

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.SEND" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "Hello Intent" -t "text/plain"
```

An explicit component name to start/launch it

```
adb shell am start -n "your.package.name/package.nameOf.Activity"
```

An explicit component name and an extra string

```
adb shell am start -n your.AppPckage.name/package.nameOf.Activity --es "key" "value"
```

So many with the --e| es you can send the extra data in the string
here

--e mean only extra data

If you use --es that mean it will stop the any existing a activity and properly start activity with extra string data.

As per your need you can choose any one of the combination. 
For more reference you  use [@seal loyola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769716/how-to-send-string-intent-extra-value-from-command-line/26517290#26517290) answer

Comment: hello. how i can launch chooser intent for file via adb?

Comment: hi сергей,adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -t "text/plain" you can use like this if you remove the -t option all app will come as choose

Comment: it is will be work with file? for example share picture on bluetooth or another social network app

Comment: Yes it will work you need to pass the correct type ie -t images/* something like that

Comment: for bluetooth sharing type would be -t application/bluetooth type find the correct mime type and for sharing action need to pipe