# How attach Tag intent extra for NFC-Tag scan simulation through ADB shell?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, nfc, activity-manager

I am trying to execute

`adb shell am start -W -a android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED -d "https://www.google.de"`

in a way that would be similar to an actual NFC-Tag scan which has some URI (SmartPoster).

This is necessary, as the above command works e.g. with Chrome but not as a deeplink into a Capacitor app.

As far as I've discovered, it is necessary to send some extra data to this intent in order for this to work correctly as a deeplink for my use case.

However, I'm not really an android-dev and the docs are lacking examples regarding the correct syntax and contents of these extras.

According to
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec

These are the possible extra options to set:

```
-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>
--esn <EXTRA_KEY>
--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE>
--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>
--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>
--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>
--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE>
--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]
--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]
--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]
```

(copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26517290)

And there seems to be a new option for string arrays:

```
[--esa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_STRING_VALUE...]]
(to embed a comma into a string escape it using "\,")
```

(copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28638589)

According to [google](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/nfc/Tag#tag-dispatch), the `EXTRA_TAG` ist passed as the extra for the intent.

> When a tag is discovered, a Tag object is created and passed to a
> single activity via the NfcAdapter#EXTRA_TAG extra in an
> android.content.Intent via android.content.Context#startActivity.

> Mandatory extra containing the [Tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/nfc/Tag) that was discovered for the
> ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, and
> ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED intents.

The value of `EXTRA_TAG` is `android.nfc.extra.TAG` - [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#extra_tag)

---

So my best guess currently is that something like this might work:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED -d "https://www.google.de" --es android.nfc.extra.Tag 'flattened object?!'`

***Question:*** Does anybody know how to execute this correctly?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you already know and what you don't know about the tag content and the app reading the tag.

In the most simple case, reading the Intent `data` (or `dataString`) will be enough.

I am myself looking for the same kind of information as I don't have the specifications of the NFC tag the app should read.
So your first guess is probably the right one:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED -d "https://www.google.de"
```

But maybe your NFC tag contains the url in the extra tag you mentioned. In that case, that would be:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED --es android.nfc.extra.Tag "https://www.google.de"
```

It is also possible that the url is stored in one of the NDEF messages, as [it is another option to carry data](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/nfc/nfc#obtain-info).
I personally did not manage to find the correct `adb` command to trigger that intent but that little bit might help some others.